# I can't copy or cut any thing in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to copy or crop something in VSC, the cursor appears the same as in the picture and nothing is copied.
This happens when I use Ctrl + C or Ctrl + X, but when I press the right button and then choose Copy or Cut, it doesn't.

What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Firstly stack overflow is for programming second did you select what you wanted to copy?

Comment: @Omar shaban -Which VS Code extensions did you use? Please check whether there are conflicting shortcut keys in "keybindings.json"(user).